# Writing CSV file to a request body of Spring Reactive WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I have a CSV file that I want to add as a request body of a WebClient PUT call. The server only accepts calls with `Content-type : text/csv` (the server is external, so this isn't something I can change).

Currently I'm using `BodyInsertors.fromResource()` method along with a `PathResource` however I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Content type 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters$$Lambda$1298/0x00000001008ae440; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters$$Lambda$1298/0x00000001008ae440
```

My code is:

```
Resource resource = new PathResource(Path.of("file.txt"));
assert resource.exists(); // true
assert resource.isReadable(); // true
this.webClient
    .put()
    .uri(location)
    .contentType(WebClientConfiguration.MEDIA_TYPE_TEXT_CSV) // new MediaType("text", "csv")
    .bodyValue(BodyInserters.fromResource(resource))
    .retrieve()
    .toBodilessEntity();
```

I imagine I may have to register proper codecs when building my WebClient but I'm unaware how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake was using `.bodyValue(BodyInserters.fromResource(resource))` instead of `.body(BodyInserters.fromResource(resource))` in the webClient call.

The working code is:

```
    this.webClient
            .put()
            .uri(location)
            .contentType(WebClientConfiguration.MEDIA_TYPE_TEXT_CSV)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(resource))
            .retrieve()
            .toBodilessEntity()
```